# Element send keys to a popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi Im trying to enter a post code into a popup and am wondering if i am inputting the wrong xpath?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Im using web driver and a find element by x path to try and locate and then input using send keys..

any advice would be greatly appreciated !

CODE:

```
  #Add Post code
    enter_post_code = wd.find_element_by_xpath ('/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]')
    random_wait_time = random.randrange(3.0, 6.0)
    print(random_wait_time)
    time.sleep(random_wait_time)
    enter_post_code.send_keys("1234")
    enter_post_code.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    
    
    Error Message:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-7de69d34215b> in <module>
          4 print(random_wait_time)
          5 time.sleep(random_wait_time)
    ----> 6 enter_post_code.send_keys("7162")
          7 enter_post_code.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/gpu_buy_bot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
        475                 value = self._upload(local_file)
        476 
    --> 477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
        478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
        479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/gpu_buy_bot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
        631             params = {}
        632         params['id'] = self._id
    --> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
        634 
        635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/gpu_buy_bot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
        319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
        320         if response:
    --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
        322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
        323                 response.get('value', None))
    
    ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/gpu_buy_bot/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
        240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
        241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
    --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
        243 
        244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
    
    ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

Comment: Can you share page URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the Xpath from absolute to relative and give it a try.
Use some extensions like SelectorsHub to generate a relative xpath.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.